# accessing static fields from different application

Tags: android, class, static

I have a bad feeling about this question but...

Given this class

```
class A {

    public static final String field = "I_m_a_field";

}
```

in the package *com.uselessoftware.A* and compiled as **A.apk**.

Is it possible to read the static field from a different application in a different package? Lets suppose (all pseudo):

```
class B {

    void readField() {

        iDontKnow obj = loadExternalClass("com.uselessoftware.A", "A");
        String externalField = obj.readStaticAsString(obj, "field");

    }

}
```

in the package *com.uselessoftware.B* and compiled as **B.apk**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Context _external_context = createPackageContext("com.uselessoftware.A", context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE + Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
Class<?> _external_class = _external_context.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.uselessoftware.A");        
Field _external_field = _external_class.getField("field");
String _field = (String) _external_field.get(null);
```

is not due to me, found [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ce374dcf32cd0725?fwc=1&pli=1) googling.